# Start particle animation on-birth with geo-nodes?

Tags: animation, particles, animation-nodes, geometry-nodes

This is really old problem that I among many others had, which is about animated particle instances.

Essentially what I'd like is for each particle to start their animations when they are emitted, not globally at the same time based on the timeline. To my knowledge, this was only possible previously with *Animation Nodes* using shapekeys, but I was wondering if this is possible now with the new geometry nodes, using any kind of animations, not just shapekey animations?